# What is the use of reset_index() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

While reading this [article](https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html), I came across this statement.

```
order_total = df.groupby('order')["ext price"].sum().rename("Order_Total").reset_index()
```

Other than `reset_index()` method call, everything else is clear to me. 
My question is what will happen if I don't call `reset_index()` considering the given below sequence?

```
order_total = df.groupby('order')["ext price"].sum().rename("Order_Total").reset_index()
df_1 = df.merge(order_total)
df_1["Percent_of_Order"] = df_1["ext price"] / df_1["Order_Total"]
```

I tried to understand about this method from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html, but couldn't understand what does it mean to *reset the index* of a dataframe.

Comment: `groupby`, as the name says, groups your content by a key and sets the key as the index. `reset_index` resets the index(column) to a regular column and uses a numeric sequence as new index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think better here is use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new `Series` with same size like original DataFrame filled by aggregate values, so `merge` is not necessary:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':list('abcdef'),
         'ext price':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'order':list('aaabbb')
})


order_total1 = df_1.groupby('order')["ext price"].transform('sum')
df_1["Percent_of_Order"] = df_1["ext price"] / order_total1
print (df_1)
   A  ext price order  Percent_of_Order
0  a          5     a          0.357143
1  b          3     a          0.214286
2  c          6     a          0.428571
3  d          9     b          0.600000
4  e          2     b          0.133333
5  f          4     b          0.266667
```

> My question is what will happen if I don't call reset_index() considering the sequence?

Here is `Series` before `reset_index()`, so after `reset_index` is converting `Series` to 2 columns DataFrame, first column is called by index name and second column by `Series` name.

```
order_total = df_1.groupby('order')["ext price"].sum().rename("Order_Total")
print (order_total)
order
a    14
b    15
Name: Order_Total, dtype: int64

print (type(order_total))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (order_total.name)
Order_Total

print (order_total.index.name)
order

print (order_total.reset_index())
  order  Order_Total
0     a           14
1     b           15
```

Reason why is necessry in your code to 2 columns DataFrame is no parameter in `merge`. It means it use parameter `on` by intersection of common columns names between both DataFrames, here `order` column.

Comment: This is really in-depth. Thanks. One question : What is this magic `list('abcdef')`, I was expecting `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`.

Comment: @SauravSahu the `list` function when applied over an iterable creates an `list` with its elements. For instance, `list((1,2,3))` produces `[1, 2, 3]`, and `list('a')` will produce `['a']`.

Answer (score 6):

A simplified explanation is that;
`reset_index()` takes the current index, and places it in column 'index'. Then it recreates a new 'linear' index for the data-set.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([20,30,40,50],index=[2,3,4,5])

    0
2  20
3  30
4  40
5  50

df.reset_index()

   index   0
0      2  20
1      3  30
2      4  40
3      5  50
```

Answer (score 5):

Reset Index will create index starting from 0 and remove if there is any column set as index.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "name": [
            "Hello Kitty",
            "Hello Puppy",
            "It is an Helloexample",
            "for stackoverflow",
            "Hello World",
        ],
    }
)
newdf = df.set_index('ID')

print(newdf.reset_index())
```

Output Before `reset_index()`:

```
                     name
ID                       
1             Hello Kitty
2             Hello Puppy
3   It is an Helloexample
4       for stackoverflow
5             Hello World
```

Output after `reset_index()`:

```
   ID                   name
0   1            Hello Kitty
1   2            Hello Puppy
2   3  It is an Helloexample
3   4      for stackoverflow
4   5            Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> My question is what will happen if I don't call reset_index() considering the sequence?

You will have a multi-index formed by the keys you have applied group-by statement on.
for eg- 'order' in your case. 
Specific to the article, difference in indices of two dataframes may cause wrong merges (done after the group-by statement).

Hence, a reset-index is needed to perform the correct merge.